# yarn start doesn't work after npx create-react-app

Tags: create-react-app, yarnpkg, npm-start

I created a react app in Mac terminal:

```
npx create-react-app robofriends
cd my-app
yarn-start
```

I get the following error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _FSEventStreamCreate<br>
  Referenced from: /robofriends/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents/build/Release/fse.node<br>
  Expected in: flat namespace


dyld: Symbol not found: _FSEventStreamCreate<br>
  Referenced from: ./my-app/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents/build/Release/fse.node<br>
  Expected in: flat namespace

error Command failed with exit code 1.<br>
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.`
```

Node version: v14.11.0

NPM version: 6.14.8

macOS Catalina version 10.15.5

My package.json file:

```json
{
  "name": "robofriends",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is yarn start, not yarn-start. And before, cd means 'change directory'. You have to do `cd robofriends` (since is the name of the directory) to get into the directory and then run the command `yarn start`.